# doxygen XML output: meaning of "@nn" in tag text?

Tags: xml, enums, doxygen

I need to understand an aspect of the XML files generated by doxygen from C headers: the use of '`@`' followed by a number ("`@nn`") in the text of some tags.

I've seen this notation used in two cases (but there may be more).

In one case `@nn` seems to be a placeholder for the name of an anonymous element like an enum. For example, an enum declaration like this.

```
enum {
   int ANONYMOUS_XYZ = 4;
};
```

generates XML like this:

```
  <memberdef kind="enum" id="..." prot="public" static="no">
    <name>@5</name>
    <enumvalue id="..." prot="public">
      <name>ANONYMOUS_XYZ</name>
      <initializer>= 4</initializer>
  </memberdef>
```

I understand what doxygen is doing here, but I want to understand why doxygen is doing it. Why not simply omit the <name> tag? Since it's there, what does `@5` refer to? If nothing else, I need to understand this use of '`@`' to be sure about whether/when I can ignore it.

In the other case, a struct declaration like this.

```
typedef struct {
    struct {
        int abc;
    } abcStruct;
} abcTypedef;
```

.generates (in part) XML like this:

```
  <compounddef id="..." kind="struct" prot="public">
    <compoundname>abcTypedef</compoundname>
    <sectiondef kind="public-attrib">
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="..." prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type>struct abcTypedef::@28</type>
        <definition>struct abcTypedef::@28 abcTypedef::abcStruct</definition>
        <argsstring />
        <name>abcStruct</name>
      </memberdef>
    </sectiondef>
  </compounddef>
```

Here `@nn` apparently refers to a real element name (in this case abcStruct). I need to know how to find that name, so that I can make a program get it.

Answer (score 1):

The `@nn` are placeholders for nameless types. Doxygen internally gives such types a unique name, so they can be referred to, as your second example nicely demonstrates.

In the output they are normally omitted. The XML output is more a dump of doxygen's internals, so there they are still visible.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it seems to present me with an impossible problem. My program uses the XML generated by two builds of a project to identify the differences between the builds. If one build refers to this particular typedef as "@28" and the next refers to it as "@29," how can I tell that they represent the same element?